# React mapping nested data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem with my React app. When I post a new project to my backend, I click the button to return me to the site dashboard where I can view a list of projects, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

### Main.jsx

Map Function:

```
{props.sites.map((site) => (
 <tr key={site.id}>
 <td data-label="Project">{site.site.name}</td>
          ... //remaining code
```

However, if I reload the page, all the data is shown.

In *React Developer Tools*, if I look at how props are passed, I can see `name` as one of the pieces of available data.

```
|_sites
  |_ 0
   |_id" 22
   |_site
      |_id: 44
      |_name: "test"
```

However, `name` is nested under `site` which is nested under `sites`.

When using the `.map` function, I have to use the keyword `site` to render a list of sites. Is this causing a conflict with the keyword site that is already in my backend data structure?

```
    this.state = {
      sites: [],
      siteFormData: {
        name: '',
      },
   }
```

If so, what is the best practice to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

From your array structure it seems that you made a mistake once you tried to access `site.site.name` which does not really exist. Instead it should be `site.name`.

Technically in the first case `site.site` becomes `undefined` which does not have a `name` property and that's why you got that error message.

Just correct the line as the following:

```
<td data-label="Project">{site.name}</td>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I tried that which does remove the error but doesn't list the name if the project. However,  if I go one level up to site.id, it will return the I'd number (22) in the table.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(props.sites)` to see what are the properties and values? Based on that we can figure out where is trick.

Answer (score 2):

With React it is a common thing to use [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for such purposes, i.e. to avoid above confusion you may go, like:

```
{props.sites.map(({id,site}) => (
 <tr key={id}>
 <td data-label="Project">{site.name}</td>
```

Or even go a bit further, since `key` doesn't necessarily have to correspond to your object properties:

```
{props.sites.map(({site:{name}},key) => (
 <tr key={key}>
 <td data-label="Project">{name}</td>
```